# Is $page a global variable in wordpress?

Tags: globals

I am having a problem with a local $page variable, especially when using it in The Loop. Is it a reserved variable of Wordpress? Also where can I find a list of all those global variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is an "inside the Loop" global.

> $page (int) The page of the post, as specified by the query var page.
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables

It is setup and used by [`setup_postdata`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6.1/wp-includes/query.php#L3642) which executes at every iteration of a standard Loop. Though meant for use inside the Loop, the variable would still be set after the Loop to the last data it was given (unless specifically unset and I don't think it is, but am not swearing to that).

Comment: But how can a variable become global only in a loop?

Comment: the_post() initializes them?

Comment: @Maxwell : see the edit

Answer (score 0):

The [wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/) is definitely your friend finding such information... :) and, yes, `$post` is one of wordpress's [Global Variables](http://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables).